# Determine branch in post-update hook

Tags: git, hook

I have a git (gitosis) repo where every developer have a main branch. 
I have a script in post-update hook that rebuild main web site and test websites for every developer on every PUSH.

I want to rebuild only site corresponding to the committed branch, but don't know how to determine committed branch name. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each argument to the post-update is the name of a ref which was updated by the push, and a branch is a ref whose name looks like `refs/heads/<branch>` so a script to do what you want would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

for ref in "$@"
do
  case "$ref" in
    refs/heads/*) /path/to/rebuild-site `basename $ref`;;
  esac
done
```